# Target an xml element using xmlSearch (xpath), then create a new child element within that element coldfusion 8

Tags: xml, xpath, coldfusion, coldfusion-8

I am trying to write new elements inside an element that I have targeted with its id attribute

Here is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<webpages>
  <course id="fteCharts">
    <linkName>FTE Charts</linkName>
    <link>index.cfm</link>
    <linkInfo>Looking for a new job or rotational experience, the links to NRC Jobs, solicitations of interest and rotational opportunities are provided. Would you like to become a leader in the NRC. The NRC offers a number of leadership development programs. The Leadership Development link provides you a list of these programs.</linkInfo>
  </course>
  <course id="matrix">
    <linkName>Skills Matrix</linkName>
    <link>index.cfm</link>
    <linkInfo>Skills Matrix Link. The NRC offers a number of leadership development programs. The Leadership Development link provides you a list of these programs.</linkInfo>
    <subLink>
        <name>Adminstrator Tool Kit 2</name>
        <url>http://r2.nrc.gov/drs/careertools/admintoolkit.pdf</url>
    </subLink>
    <subLink>
        <name>Technical Tool Kit Matrix 2</name>
        <url>http://r2.nrc.gov/drs/careertools/technicaltoolkit.pdf</url>
    </subLink>
  </course>
</webpages>
```

Here is how I have pulled the data for this element in my cfc:

```
<cfset params = toString( getHttpRequestData().content ) />

<cfset args = #deserializeJSON(params)# />

<cfset bPath = "e:\webapps\NRCNewsApps\rmsi" />

<cffile action="read" file="#bPath#\xml\nav.xml" variable="myxml">  
<cfset thedoc = XmlParse(myxml)>

<cfset arynode = XmlSearch(thedoc, "/webpages/course[ @id = '#args.linkID#' ]") />
<cfset xmlCourse = arynode[1] />
```

So `xmlCourse` then returns the course that I want to add nodes to. It is an array with the xml data I need:

```
XmlElemNew(xmlCourse, "subLink");
```

I want to create new blank xml nodes (named "sublink") inside the targeted course, I have been trying all day and haven't figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to save the xml file to your ram or to disk the read it and search the saved document and attach the nodes by reading the data and appending them using file and append commands. I am not sure why you would want to insert empty nodes. What are you trying to accomplish? But there are CFC files also that will read xml and convert it to a struct I have used it before but never found any real practical application for using it.